# Return boolean from method that calls an Int

Tags: java, int, return, boolean

As per instructions: *Write a static method that takes one integer as a formal parameter and returns a Boolean value of True if the parameter value is even and False if the it odd*. It would seem my method *must* call an int instead of a boolean. With that being said I don't know how to return a boolean from a method that calls an int. I've tried this but it doesn't work.

EDIT - Language is JAVA.
\nEDIT 2 - For anyone looking at this in the future, I originally meant to type private static int result. Not private static boolean result. That mistake ended up fixing my code.

```
}
    private static boolean result(int userIn)
    {
        if (userIn % 2 == 0)
        {
            int yes = 1;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "call an int". "Call" is something you do with methods, not numbers. Also, your code looks correct. What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 4):

Your original question didn't actually specify programming language, and it's not clear why you think you need to "call an int".

However in most C-descendent languages, and keeping with the style of your code quote, the following should work

```
private static boolean result(int userIn)
{
    return (userIn % 2) == 0;
}
```

The expression `(userIn % 2) == 0` will evaluate to a boolean (or your language's representation of one).

It is a common anti-idiom for people learning to program to do something like:

```
if (some condition is true)
then
    return TRUE
else
    return FALSE
```

Most (modern) programming languages allow you to simply return the result of evaluating a boolean condition, or to assign it to a suitably typed variable.

Thus

```
boolean result = (myvariable >= 10)
```

has the same result as, but is much more readable than:

```
boolean result
if (myvariable >= 10)
    result = TRUE
else
    result = FALSE
```

This may be what the person who set the assignment is wanting you to learn from it.

Comment: That looks more like a comment than an answer. Your code returns the same result as OP's.

Comment: The OP seems to be struggling with the concept of having  an `int` supplied and return a boolean. I'm just showing them how it's done, and why their code snippet is overly-complex.

Comment: @frillybob So does yours.

Comment: Got it thanks, I meant to have private static int, not boolean. Somehow that got changed but ended up working. My issue was I didn't know I could mix the boolean and int together. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Even with the function declared `private static int` this approach should still work. Java should coerce a boolean to an int.